# Get Response from Console Application (command prompt in windows)

Tags: c#, web-services, rest, console-application

I have Web UI, Client_Console, Loader_Console.

Please consider my below two scenarios

Scenario 1:
The Client_Console will call the WebService (REST), through that only I'm passing inputs it will invoke the other console application (loader_console), This works fine and I'm able to get the response from the loader_console and successfully displayed in Client_console.

Scenario 2:
From Web UI I need to pass the Inputs to Client_console which will call the webservice and pass the input to the Loader_console.

Now my problem is i can't able to get the response from the Client_Console when all the operations are done.

Below i include some part of my code

```
        Process InvokeTool = new Process();
        InvokeTool.StartInfo.FileName = toolToInvoke;


        InvokeTool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

        InvokeTool.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        InvokeTool.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        InvokeTool.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        try
        {
            InvokeTool.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var exceptn = ex.ToString();
            lbl_Response.Text = "ERROR : Could not find the tool specified in the client json config file";
            return;
        }

        StreamWriter writer = InvokeTool.StandardInput;


        writer.WriteLine(sourcefolderURL);
        writer.WriteLine(jsonFileLocation);
        writer.WriteLine(fieldSeperator);
        writer.WriteLine("NO");

        StreamReader reader = InvokeTool.StandardOutput;
        //InvokeTool.Kill();
        //InvokeTool.CloseMainWindow();

        var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        string[] responseArray = result.Split(':');
```

Please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Are you calling the console client from the web application? that means that console application is launched in a non interactive environment (Windows service session), so **you can't** see the console application running.

If you need the console applicaation You should think on a console application running on an open session and listening in a port, the web app should stablish communication with console client using this port and console client should interact with web app by receiving instructions using that port.

You should stablish a communication channel. There are many ways to achieve it. Try one of these:

1. Send the response to a registry entry. (then read the registry form web app) : [**Registry Class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Send the response to a text file, the web app must open the file to review it: [How to: Write to a Text File (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx)
3. stablish communication using an IPC Channel: [.NET Remoting Using a New IPC Channel](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/csharp/cs_syntax/remoting/article.php/c9251/NET-Remoting-Using-a-New-IPC-Channel.htm)

Comment: Hi Juan Yes I'm calling the Console_client from the web Application. Is it possible to get the response form the Console_Client (when operation is done) ?

Comment: I have improved the answer with more details and scenarios